# CustomSort on multi-column ListCollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, listcollectionview

Being new to C#, I just found out that CustomSort clears SortDescriptions, and now I am a bit stuck on how to allow custom multi-column sorting of my datagrid.

You can see my code in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534311/sortdescriptioncollection-is-reset-when-using-customsort/47534952)

The particular line that I am trying to figure out is this:

```
lcv.CustomSort = new IntegerSorter(lcv.SortDescriptions);
```

In my IntegerSort custom sort, I am checking if SortDescriptions contains more than one column, and if so - perform the multi-column sort accordingly. This however relies on the fact that each time the user does a shift+click on the column, it appends the sort description to the ListCollectionView. Which doesn't work, since it is reset after every custom sort I do.

Are there any known workarounds for this? What is the proper way of doing a multi-column sort with a custom sort?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER, winforms != wpf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first create a custom sort, you give it the list of sort descriptions that the ListCollectionView has.

The next time the user shift clicks, if `lcv.SortDescriptions` is empty, `lcv.CustomSort` won't be `null`. It'll be the `IntegerSort` you gave it last time around, and it'll still have that list of SortDescriptions you passed to its constructor. So grab it:

```
var intSort = lcv.CustomSort as IntegerSort;
```

Make a new collection, and create a new `IntegerSort` with the new list.

If `IntegerSort` doesn't make the SortDescriptions available as a public property, make it so it does.

Or if you want to keep that private, write a new constructor for IntegerSort for this purpose:

```
public IntegerSort(IntegerSort oldSort, SortDecsription add, SortDecsription remove = null)
{
    //  Put the new collection together
}
```

Use like so:

```
lcv.CustomSort = new IntegerSort(lcv.CustomSort as IntegerSort, sortedColumnDescription);
```

Comment: That was so simple! Thank you! I completely didn't realize that CustomSort is something I Set and Get and therefore it would maintain the property.